# Meter la variable en el Atributo

Tags: javascript, html, template

**[EDIT]**

Lo he conseguido de una manera, pero creo que se puede seguir simplificando, ya que se está repitiendo una estructura en la que sólo cambia el data-prefix:

```
// TEMPLATE HTML
<template  id="temp-row-input">
    <div class="box">
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name=""></label>
        <div class="sortable_p" draggable="true">

            
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='t_' name=""/>
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='v_' name=""/>
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='c_' name=""/>
              


                <button type="button" class="btn-event-disAble" title="Deshabilitar">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-event-erase" title="Borrar">-</button>
                <div class="draggl">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 


//FUNCTION JS

addMagnitude(el, mag) {
    var el = el.parentNode;

    var temMag = document.querySelector(`#temp-row-input`).innerHTML;

    let magnitude = document.createElement("div");
    magnitude.innerHTML = temMag;

    magnitude.querySelector("input[data-prefix=t_]").setAttribute('name', mag);
    magnitude.querySelector("input[data-prefix=v_]").setAttribute('name', mag);
    magnitude.querySelector("input[data-prefix=c_]").setAttribute('name', mag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un lio de código para algo tan simple, o bien no eh terminado de entender tu objetivo, los inputs ya están, recuerda que con la función `setAttribute()` puedes **setear** cualquier atributo, tienes que pasarle 2 parametros: 1 el nombre del atributo, 2: el valor del atributo ejemplo:

```
DOMelement.setAttribute('name','algun-nombre');
```

Te muestro un ejemplo con un boton que le asignará el atributo `name` a un `input`, espero pueda servirte de pauta para poder solucionar tu problema:

```js
const btnAddAttr = document.querySelector('#addAttr');
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

console.log(input);

btnAddAttr.addEventListener('click', function(){

  input.setAttribute('name','my-input');
  
  console.log(input);
  
  

})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Soy un input"/>

<button id="addAttr">Asignar atributo NAME</button>
```

Nota que cuando la aplicación inicia el `input` no tiene el atributo `name` cuando presionas el botón, le asignamos dicho atributo `name`

Comment: Si, es justo lo que me gustaría hacer, pero eso, si mal no estoy entendiendo, tendría que hacer 3 botones distintos para 3 nombres distintos, entiendo, no?

Comment: Vale, voy a editar, porque lo he conseguido hacer de una forma, PERO, creo que se podría incluso simplificar.

Comment: Bueno, de hecho el **boton** Solo era de ejemplo para que pudieras ver como se le asigna un atributo a un elemento, en realidad no necesitas ningún botón, solo la lógica en donde se le asigna el atributo al elemento, el resto le toca a tu imaginación, y estoy de acuerdo en que puedes simplificar muchas cosas en tu codigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Tesla, me gusta que me deis pistas mas que la solucion =3

Comment: En realidad con el ejemplo que te puse, tendrías que haber podido realizar lo que deseabas, más que una "pista" fue un ejemplo para que pudieras aplicarlo a tu proyecto. Saludos